# boto3 events / eventBridge configuration for localhost

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, serverless

I can't seem to find boto3 additional client parameters for eventBridge. I'm trying to configure the client to work with local eventBridge plugin. What is the best way to find the client parameters?

```
eventBridge = boto3.client('events', [additional params])
```

Looking at documentation
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/events.html#client doesn't seem to provide any information on additional params. What is the best way to find them?

I'm running a python lambda code using serverless framework and trying to make use of local eventBridge plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-offline-aws-eventbridge) and trying to make eventBridge client connect to local serverless offlince eventbrige. NPM package Readme shows show to configure eventBrdige client using JS. I'm trying to achieve the same thing with python/boto3

Answer (score 0):

All boto3 services use same core client which is documented [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/core/session.html#boto3.session.Session.client):

> client(service_name, region_name=None, api_version=None, use_ssl=True, verify=None, endpoint_url=None, aws_access_key_id=None, aws_secret_access_key=None, aws_session_token=None, config=None)